# Ubuntu 18.04.1 kernel upgrade stuck at setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, kernel

I am trying to upgrade kernel on my laptop and as I'm doing that very often I never had an issue until last time when I was able to fix the issue with running:

```
sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```

As there is a new kernel version, upgrade got stuck again and it's not moving from there:

```
...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic (4.15.0-36.39) ...
```

I have also checked dmesg but I cannot find any issue there.

Command execution were as follows:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt list --upgradable
sudo apt upgrade
```

I would like to skip the "workaround" part and be able to upgrade kernel/packages normally. Hope you can help me!

Please let me know if you need any logs.

Thank you!

**Update:**

As mentioned by [cspan51](https://askubuntu.com/users/838078/cspan51), I don't have nvidia graphics, I have only intel.

I was able to fix the issue with restart of the laptop, and when fully ready I have started Software Updater, which seems does not have the same problem, tho I am not sure is this correct because under the hood I would say tools are the same.

**Solution**

Secure boot was the culprit but disabling it does not solve the problem since I don't want to disable it, so actually solution is to do package upgrade with Software Updater (GUI) instead of terminal apt-get/apt .. because in terminal version, it does never asks for secure boot password

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem with my laptop, which has a discrete Nvidia graphics card. I did some research and found that this is problem if [fairly common](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998950/dpkg-stops-during-configuration-of-linux-headers-cant-update-or-reconfigure) if your machine has an Nvidia graphics card.

I was able to get past this problem by running killing all `apt` and `dpkg` processes:
`sudo killall apt && sudo killall dpkg`

Then this to finish configuring the packages:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

After that, the setup finished like it normally does.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have only intel graphics, will update an question. Please note that I have tried that but it did not work.

Comment: I had no nvidia graphics (on this computer at least) but the `killall` commands helped to get unstuck! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Disabling Secure Boot in bios helped in my case.

Comment: This seems more suited for a comment, next time try commenting to retreive more information

Comment: @j-money A solution should be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Don't work, SecureBoot disabled

Answer (score 0):

Killing all apt and dpkg processes is solved my problem. To find processes with
`ps aux | grep apt` and `ps aux | grep dpkg`

After that `kill -9 processnumber <id>`
to make it work.